# Generar un listado de fechas

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

```
SELECT NominaD.tipo_nom,nominad.anonomina,NominaD.num,NominaD.CVE_PERS,
PERSONAL.NOMBRE_PER,INCAPACIDADESNOM.Fecha_ini ,incapacidadesnom.fecha_apli,
CARINCDDESG.Clave_Incap,TIPOS_INCA.DESCRIPCION AS "Desc_TipoIncap",
CARINCDDESG.Dias
FROM NominaD                                                                                                     
LEFT OUTER JOIN NOMINA ON (NOMINAD.CONSENOM=Nomina.CONSENOM)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSONAL PERSONAL ON (PERSONAL.CVE_PERS = NominaD.CVE_PERS)     
left outer JOIN CARGASINCIDENCIASC CARINCC  ON (CARINCC.NO_CORTE = NominaD.NO_CORTE)
left outer JOIN CARGASINCIDENCIASD CARINCD  ON (CARINCD.NO_CORTE = CARINCC.NO_CORTE)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CARGASINCIDENCIASDDESG CARINCDDESG ON (CARINCD.NO_CORTE = CARINCDDESG.NO_CORTE and carincd.renglon=carincddesg.renglon) and CARINCDDESG.cve_pers=NominaD.cve_pers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOS_INCAPACIDADLAB TIPOS_INCA ON (TIPOS_INCA.CLAVE_INCAP   = CARINCDDESG.Clave_Incap)     
LEFT OUTER JOIN INCAPACIDADESNOM ON (CARINCDDESG.TIPO = 'D' AND INCAPACIDADESNOM.NUM_INCAPACIDAD = CARINCDDESG.NUM_INCAPACIDAD)  
where(NOMINAD.NUM BETWEEN 13 AND 13) 
AND (NOMINAD.TIPO_NOM= 000)
and (NOMINA.FECHA_INI= '01/07/21') AND (NOMINA.FECHA_FIN= '15/07/21')
and (CARINCC.STATUS='A') 
and (CARINCD.VALIDADO='V')
AND (CARINCDDESG.TIPO='D') 
Order by NominaD.CVE_PERS
```

El resultado de esta consulta arroja la siguiente tabla

| tipo_nom | anonomina | num | CVE_PERS | NOMBRE_PER | Fecha_ini | fecha_apli | Clave_Incap | Desc_TipoIncap | Dias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 2021 | 13 | 5868 | Eduardo Antonio | 15/07/21 | 17/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 | 3 |

lo que busco generar es el siguiente listado dado que son 3 días de incapacidad entre la fecha 15/07/21 a la 17/07/21 pero el campo fehca_apli se debe de quitar para que la tabla quede de la siguiente manera:

| tipo_nom | anonomina | num | CVE_PERS | NOMBRE_PER | Fecha | Clave_Incap | Desc_TipoIncap | Dias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 2021 | 13 | 5868 | Eduardo Antonio | 15/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 | 3 |
| 000 | 2021 | 13 | 5868 | Eduardo Antonio | 16/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 | 3 |
| 000 | 2021 | 13 | 5868 | Eduardo Antonio | 17/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 | 3 |

la fecha de inicio de incapacidad y fin se guardan de esa forma en el mismo registro pero requiero generar el listado agregando a la fecha inicio los días de incapacidad sin tomar en cuanta también los sábados y domingos, espero darme a explicar y encontrar alguna respuesta para solventar el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución, está basada en una secuencia *CTE*, que se compone de las siguientes partes:

1. Un generador de números consecutivos (`1, 2, 3... N`), que nos servirá para poder ir sumando días a la fecha inicial, de manera que obtengamos todos los días que hay entre ambas fechas. Una expresión como la siguiente, nos dará un consecutivo de 1 a 100. Si en la práctica hay registros que tengan más de 99 días de separación, aumenta el valor en esta parte.

   ```
    select rownum n from dual connect by rownum <= 100
   ```
2. La consulta que genera el resultado que presentas en la pregunta. Dado que no tengo acceso a las tablas en mi entorno de pruebas, mi CTE produce exactamente la única fila que muestras, pero puedes sustituirla por la consulta real, que no debiera dar problema.
3. Finalmente, la consulta que construye la solución, que hace un *join* entre los `Datos` de la consulta original y los `numeros`, para generar **fechas al vuelo** y obtener así todas las fechas que hay entre la inicial y final del registro (incluyendolas). Esta consulta tiene un `where` que excluye los fines de semana (cosa que has pedido, pero que no coincide con tus datos esperados, que incluyen un sábado). Ante la inconsistencia, he dejado la exclusión. Si al final, quieres ver el sábado, ajusta la cláusula `where` de esta última parte.

El código final es:

```
with
Numeros as (
select rownum n from dual connect by rownum <= 100
)
,
Datos as (
select   '000' tipo_nom
       , 2021 anonomina
       , 13 num
       , 5868 CVE_PERS
       , 'Eduardo Antonio' NOMBRE_PER
       , to_date('2021-07-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') fecha_ini
       , to_date('2021-07-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD') fecha_fin
       , '01' Clave_Incap
       , 'riesgo mayor 4' Desc_TipoIncap
       , 3 Dias
  from dual       
)
select   Datos.tipo_nom
       , Datos.anonomina
       , Datos.num
       , Datos.CVE_PERS
       , Datos.NOMBRE_PER
       , Datos.fecha_ini + Numeros.n - 1 Fecha
       , to_char(Datos.fecha_ini + Numeros.n - 1, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=spanish') DiaSemana
       , Datos.Clave_Incap
       , Datos.Desc_TipoINcap
       , Datos.Dias
  from Datos
       inner join Numeros on Datos.fecha_ini + Numeros.n - 1 <= Datos.fecha_fin
 where to_char(Datos.fecha_ini + Numeros.n - 1, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=spanish') not in ('Sábado', 'Domingo')
```

Lo que devuelve el siguiente resultado:

| TIPO_NOM | ANONOMINA | NUM | CVE_PERS | NOMBRE_PER | FECHA | DIASEMANA | CLAVE_INCAP | DESC_TIPOINCAP | DIAS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 2021 | 13 | 5868 | Eduardo Antonio | 15-JUL-21 | Jueves | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 | 3 |
| 000 | 2021 | 13 | 5868 | Eduardo Antonio | 16-JUL-21 | Viernes | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 | 3 |

Puedes probar la solución en [oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/liw4zkp4dudidwz3h8qceuw8d)

Comment: Que tal , probaré de esa forma , también encontré como solventarlo un tanto similar a lo que me compartes, lo dejaré en el post.

Answer (score 1):

Esta fue la solución que encontré:

```
SELECT TABLAG.CVE_PERS,TABLAG.NOMBRE_PER,TABLAG.FECHA,TABLAG.CLAVE_INCAP,TABLAG."Desc_TipoIncap" 
    FROM( SELECT NominaD.tipo_nom,nominad.anonomina,NominaD.num,NominaD.CVE_PERS,
          PERSONAL.NOMBRE_PER,CARINCDDESG.Fecha_ini+level-1 FECHA ,--CARINCDDESG.fecha_fin,
          CARINCDDESG.Clave_Incap,TIPOS_INCA.DESCRIPCION  "Desc_TipoIncap",level,CARINCDDESG.TIPO,CARINCD.VALIDADO,CARINCC.STATUS,
          NOMINA.FECHA_INI,NOMINA.FECHA_FIN
          FROM NominaD                                                                                                     
          LEFT OUTER JOIN NOMINA ON (NOMINAD.CONSENOM=Nomina.CONSENOM)  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSONAL PERSONAL ON (PERSONAL.CVE_PERS = NominaD.CVE_PERS)     
          left outer JOIN CARGASINCIDENCIASC CARINCC    ON (CARINCC.NO_CORTE = NominaD.NO_CORTE)
          left outer JOIN CARGASINCIDENCIASD CARINCD    ON (CARINCD.NO_CORTE = CARINCC.NO_CORTE)  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN CARGASINCIDENCIASDDESG CARINCDDESG ON (CARINCD.NO_CORTE = CARINCDDESG.NO_CORTE 
          and carincd.renglon=carincddesg.renglon) and CARINCDDESG.cve_pers=NominaD.cve_pers 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOS_INCAPACIDADLAB TIPOS_INCA   ON (TIPOS_INCA.CLAVE_INCAP   = CARINCDDESG.Clave_Incap)     
          LEFT OUTER JOIN INCAPACIDADESNOM ON (CARINCDDESG.TIPO = 'D' 
          AND INCAPACIDADESNOM.NUM_INCAPACIDAD = CARINCDDESG.NUM_INCAPACIDAD)  
          CONNECT BY PRIOR nominad.anonomina=nominad.anonomina
          and PRIOR CARINCDDESG.Fecha_ini=CARINCDDESG.Fecha_ini
          and level <=CARINCD.DIAS_INCAP
          AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('p', 10) IS NOT NULL
     ) TABLAG
    where(TABLAG.NUM BETWEEN 13 AND 13)
    AND (TABLAG.TIPO_NOM= 000)
    and (TABLAG.FECHA_INI= '01/07/21') AND (TABLAG.FECHA_FIN= '15/07/21')
    and (TABLAG.STATUS='A') 
    and (TABLAG.VALIDADO='V')
    AND (TABLAG.TIPO='D') 
    Order by TABLAG.CVE_PERS
```

Solo le agregaré una validación para que no tome en cuenta los sábados y domingos

| CVE_PERS | NOMBRE_PER | FECHA | CLAVE_INCAP | Desc_TipoIncap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5868 | CRISTOBAL BADILLO RAMIREZ | 15/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 |
| 5868 | CRISTOBAL BADILLO RAMIREZ | 16/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 |
| 6371 | FELIPE AGUILAR MARTINEZ | 07/07/21 | 01 | riesgo mayor 4 |

Comment: Es excelente que vuelvas y aportes tu propia solución al problema, sin embargo, creo que a tu respuesta le está faltando una explicación de como lo resolviste, las respuestas con sólo código generalmente son consideradas de baja calidad justamente por esa razón. Te recomiendo leer [answer]. Un saludo.